# Call jquery.ajax within ajax generated form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got a little problem here.
What I am trying to achieve to generate a modal/form with jquery/ajax and within that modal should be another ajax call (that is generated with 2 specific ids).

Hope this makes a little bit more clear:

I got my page and press "generate form". 
Then jquery loads the modal via ajax & get url: "/modal/id1/id2" (the whole form is loaded).
This still works. 
Now I want in this form a button "post form" that posts this form to the same url "/modal/id1/id2"
and overrides the current modal with the result of the "inner" ajax call.

I get this error:

```
POST http://localhost/modal/id1/id2 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:6
send jquery.min.js:6
x.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:6
(anonymous function) VM7593:4
x.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:5
```

It looks like ajax is just not working.
Here is a little bit code I use:
This code generates the first modal. Still working fine:

```
    <script>
      $('[data-toggle="view"]').on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id1 = $(this).data('id1');
        var id2 = "<?php echo $id2; ?>"
        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "offers/"+id1+"/create/"+id2,
           dataType: "html",
           success: function(response){
             $('#offerModal').html(response);
             $('#offerModal').modal('toggle');
           }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

And this is the code that is returned by the first ajax request and shown in the modal:

```
 <script>
   $('#createOffer').on('click',function(){
     $.ajax({
             type: "post",
             url: "offers/1/create/2", //url exists and is working
             data: { test: "test" },
             success: function(response){
               alert(response);
             }
          });
      });
   </script>
```

Hope you can (understand my problem and) help me with it.

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure httaccess is possible with ajax?

Comment: yes, because the first ajax call is working. i am calling the same url 2 times. one time with get and one time with post

Comment: why don't you try to put that second ajax call in the same place where the first call is. Just to see if it works that way.

Comment: I'm assuming you are doing in the target page something like: if get do this else if post do that, and the second ajax call is created in the block "if get"

Comment: It is actually not working on the same url.
There must be something wrong with my ajax post call

Comment: It could be, but unfortunately you don't post the code that you run in the target page.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the $('#createOffer') click event isn't getting set?  Maybe wrapping it inside a $(document) ready function would help:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#createOffer').on('click',function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "offers/1/create/2", //url exists and is working
                data: { test: "test" },
                success: function(response){
                   alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help you two.
I found the answer myself (thanks to ADASein little hint)
and I just made a big mistake. :/
The code I posted is working, but the view for the post url returned an error in this specific constellation.